# Jquery with CSS txtarea Live Preview with Div Function

Tags: jquery

Function: When click a button, the alt value of it will added to text area and it will show its live preview with div and the id is its alt value. On my code there is a problem, when i click the button it inserted the whole code which is , id like to remove the div tag and i like only to show the alt code but in preview it show well the desired div. Please help me! Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image').click(function(e){
        var tav    = $('#image_code').val(),
            strPos = $('#image_code')[0].selectionStart;
        front  = (tav).substring(0,strPos),
            back   = (tav).substring(strPos,tav.length); 
        $('#image_code').val(front + '<div id=\"' + $(this).attr("alt") + '\"></div>' + back).trigger('keyup');
    });
    $('#image_code').keyup(function() {
        $('#image_preview').html( $(this).val() );
    });
});
</script>

<style>
#one{
background-color: black;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
#two{
background-color: red;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
#three{
background-color: blue;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
</style>

<textarea id="image_code"></textarea>
<div id="image_preview"></div>
<button id="1" class="image" title="1" alt="one">1</button>
<button id="2" class="image" title="2" alt="two">2</button>
<button id="3" class="image" title="3" alt="three">3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This all seems rather weird, but from the best that I could understand of your question, is this what you are hoping to achieve?

```
$('.image').click(function(e){
    $('#image_code').val($(this).attr("alt")).trigger('keyup');
});
$('#image_code').keyup(function() {
    var tav    = $('#image_preview').html();
    strPos = $('#image_code')[0].selectionStart;
    front  = (tav).substring(0,strPos),
    back   = (tav).substring(strPos,tav.length); 
    $('#image_preview').html(front + '<div id=\"' + $(this).val() + '\"></div>' + back);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3aEg/

Comment: But it doesn't allow to have 2 divs on text area. I need to have unlimited. Thanks for helping me

Comment: You're using the value out of your text area to set the ID of the div. If you did that you would wind up with id="one two three one..." Is there any reason for that? Why not just move the keyup code into the click function?

Comment: What are you saying, i dont understand it. Sorry im noob. Can you tell me how. Or can you edit your code